# Equivalents with less few dots in scheme language?

Tags: scheme, racket

what are the equivalent structures with few dots for these in scheme  language

1. ’((((a . b) . c) . d) . ())
2. ’((a . ( b . ())) . ())
3. '(a . ( b . c ))
4. ’(a . (( b . c) . ()))

   for example : for '(a . (b . (c . (d . ())))) the equivalent is (a b c d e)

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as evaluating the expressions in the interpreter and observing what gets printed:

```
'((((a . b) . c) . d))
'((a b))
'(a b . c)
'(a (b . c))
```

Remember: the dot notation is just a convention, it's shown when a list structure is *improper* (that is, it doesn't end with an empty list). That's why this is printed exactly the same:

```
'(a . b)
=> '(a . b)
```

But this is printed without the dot, it's implied that the last element is an empty list, so there's no need to show it:

```
'(a b . ())
=> '(a b)
```

Read the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html) to learn more about all the quirks of the dot notation, in particular pay attention to this section:

> In general, the rule for printing a pair is as follows: use the dot notation always, but if the dot is immediately followed by an open parenthesis, then remove the dot, the open parenthesis, and the matching close parenthesis. Thus, `(0 . (1 . 2))` becomes `(0 1 . 2)`, and `(1 . (2 . (3 . ())))` becomes `(1 2 3)`.

Comment: @Lopez : in Scheme ,is letrec more general than let and can it blindly replace uses of let? pls explain me i want to understand this concept

Comment: @want2 No, you can't blindly replace let with letrec. This space is too short for an example, but your book should have an explanation of the difference.